# How to iterate a list of objects using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to iterate a list of objects in my jsp using jstl, but when I'm trying to access a parameter it returns the parameter name, here 'destination' instead of the actual value. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a part of my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${journeys}" var="journey">
    ${journey.destination}
</c:forEach>
```

Here is my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    SearchForm form = new SearchForm();
    List<Journey> journeys = form.searchJourney( request );
    request.setAttribute( "journeys", journeys );
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VIEW ).forward( request, response );
}
```

And the journey object is containing:

```
public class Journey {

    private String destination;

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.departure = destination;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<c:out value="${journey.destination}"/>
```